# Entity Relation Diagrams

Tags: database, erd, inventory-management

I am doing a project on Inventory Management System for office managing office products. As a first step, I designed the ER diagram:

[image]

Can anyone review and suggest changes?

I am really doubtful at the **Purchase Table** and its relation to **Product Table** and **Warranty Table**. Suppose I purchased 2 monitors, 3 CPU's in one purchase (5 products), then how can I trace those products in the product table. And how can I claim warranty for those items individually (Imagining the warranty for each product is different)

Comment: you don't need a category in product when you have it in product type right? thats redundant

Comment: You're repeating the same data all over the place, like same fields in product & warranty. Don't really see the whole point of warranty, if your product is just one item. Shouldn't the warranty data just be in product? Maybe same thing with purchase table.